# How to get the protocol name in PyShark?

Tags: python, tcp, protocols, scapy, pyshark

Using PyShark, how can I get a string with the name of an IP protocol from the number on the packet proto field?

For example, converting 6 to 'TCP'.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a map of protocol numbers [as defined by IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) from the [socket module of the Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) with:

```
import socket
ip_proto={v:k[8:] for (k,v) in vars(socket).items() if k.startswith('IPPROTO')}
```

This dictionary comprehension extract IP protocols from the `__dict__` attribute of the [socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) using the [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) built-in function.

And then use it as:

```
>>> ip_proto.get(1)
'ICMP'
>>> ip_proto.get(2)
'IGMP'
>>> ip_proto.get(6)
'TCP'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method to accomplish your use case using `PyShark`.

```
import pyshark
import re as regex

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
for packet in capture:
    if 'IPV6 Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = regex.search(r'(Next Header:)(.*)', str(packet.ipv6))
        protocol_type = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[0]
        protocol_number = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[1]
        print(f'(Internet Protocol: IPv6, '
              f'Protocol Type: {protocol_type}, '
              f'Protocol Number: {protocol_number}')
    elif 'IP Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = regex.search(r'(Protocol:)(.*)', str(packet.ip))
        protocol_type = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[0]
        protocol_number = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[1]
        print(f'(Internet Protocol: IPv4, '
              f'Protocol Type: {protocol_type}, '
              f'Protocol Number: {protocol_number}')
```

OUTPUT:

```
(Internet Protocol: IPv4, Protocol Type: TCP, Protocol Number: (6)
(Internet Protocol: IPv4, Protocol Type: UDP, Protocol Number: (17)
(Internet Protocol: IPv6, Protocol Type: ICMPv6, Protocol Number: (58)
truncated...
```

Here is another way to accomplish your use case using the Python module `sockets` and `PyShark`

```
import socket
import pyshark

prefix = "IPPROTO_"
protocol_table = {num:name[len(prefix):] for name,num in vars(socket).items() if name.startswith(prefix)}

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
for packet in capture:
    if 'IPV6 Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = [protocol_type for [protocol_number, protocol_type] in protocol_table.items()
                    if protocol_number == int(packet.ipv6.nxt)]
        print(protocol)
    elif 'IP Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = [protocol_type for [protocol_number, protocol_type] in protocol_table.items()
                    if protocol_number == int(packet.ip.proto)]
        print(protocol)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['TCP']
['UDP']
['ICMPV6']
truncated...
```